# (Design) Logging framework with Kafka

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

We are planning to build a logging framework and for our scale we are leaning on kafka to be a solution we wanna POC on. This is what I am thinking of now :

```
Set of ~200 application machines -----> (each independently has a built in kafka producer) --------> which write to kafka --------> we use a hdfs sink to eventually write to hdfs.
```

Is it a good idea to have the application machines direclty call kafka ? The machines get close to a billion hits / day. I dont want anything to impact the application machines. The Producer on application machines would be doing an async send. I dont think these are CPU intensive operations, but I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Or, should I be using some form of log aggegator on the client machines which aggregate chunks of logs (say by time or size) and then does a send. This would reduce the load on my kafka cluster and would reduce the work which client machines do. I am leaning towards this idea. Are there client specific log aggregators which I can use with Kafka producers ?

Any better ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK directly call kafka from application. I just want to pay your attention in the fact if you are going to use a queue based solution for communication between application and Kafka producer you should strongly think about the possible queue size. It might consume all available memory in case when Kafka doesn't available and the queue maximum capacity is so big.

Also, it make sense to consider if you need a retry logic for your Kafka producer. Usually retry logic required more resources than fire-and-forget implementation.

Not sure if understand correctly your idea about the client specific log aggregators, but if you want to read data from the log files and populate it to Kafka I would recommend you use Logstash + Kafka. So, Kafka Output Plugin might help you:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html